# Eigenvalues broken in 11.2?

Tags: bugs, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

**Bug introduced in 11.1.0 and fixed in 11.3.0**

---

The code

```
M = Flatten[Table[Flatten[Transpose[{{1, a, a, -1}[[i]] 
            UnitVector[4, i]}].{{1, a, a, -1}[[j]]
            UnitVector[4, j]}],   {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}], 1]
```

creates the diagonal matrix with diagonal

```
{1,a,a,-1,a,a^2,a^2,-a,a,a^2,a^2,-a,-1,-a,-a,1}
```

However, in Mathematica 11.2, `Eigenvalues[M]` returns me

```
{-1,-a,-a,-1,-a,-a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a^2,a^2,a}
```

Is this only me or is it a bug? In Mathematica 11.0.x, it works fine.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me ... did you report it to Wolfram?

Comment: Whereas `Eigenvalues[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, 1]` works, there is a weird error message when evaluating `Eigenvalues[M, 3]`.

Comment: I did not file it. If this is really a bug, I need to rollback to 11.0, not file a bug :(

Comment: If you don't report it, don't expect it to get fixed ...

Comment: Good hint, coolwater. So it is something in the internal representation. In fact, `Eigenvalues[Transpose[M]]` gives the correct result.

Comment: The bug is under investigation; thanks for the example.

Comment: The fix will be available in the next release.

Comment: @ilian: Great! Is there any workaround or do I have to downgrade until next release to get reliable results?

Comment: The workaround is to unpack, as in the answer.

Comment: @ilian: just got 11.3 and it is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a bug.

The problem seems to be related to the fact that some rows of your matrix are packed arrays and some are not.

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ M
(* {True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True} *)
```

Unpacking seems to avoid the problem.

```
Eigenvalues@Developer`FromPackedArray[M]
(* {-1, -1, 1, 1, -a, -a, -a, -a, a, a, a, a, a^2, a^2, a^2, a^2} *)
```

Comment: By any chance, do you know a way to disable packed arrays as a workaround?

Comment: @Matthias I do not think packed arrays can be disabled. Please do report it to WRI for the sake of everyone who may be affected by it.

Comment: This answer really doesn't deserve upvotes ... it was just an observation that it is a bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs - it deserves upvotes because it identifies the cause of the problem and provides a workaround.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree, but at least 14 others do not, as evidenced by their upvotes. The easiest solution to this is to only upvote answers you feel deserve it, and let others do the same.

Comment: "Use every man after his desert, and who should 'scape whipping? Use them after your own honor and dignity. The less they deserve, the more merit is in your bounty." (Hamlet II.ii) -- Good luck getting SE voting to correspond to the degree of deserving.